# How do I uninstall a ruby version installed via source?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, ruby

I installed a version (1.9.3-p194) of ruby via source using `make install` and realized this may have been the wrong route to take. Upon doing this, I realized this was a mistake and I should be using a solution such as rvm to address my ruby versions within the OS.

I looked to see if an `uninstall` existed to be ran in conjunction with `make` and it didn't.

I then proceeded to install rvm and add the aforementioned version in to my list of managed rubies within rvm which is not listed as ext-ruby-1.9.3-p194.

```
rvm rubies

   ext-ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default**
```

When I perform an rvm remove, it simply removes it from the rubies list however it still exists within `/usr/local/bin`. I am not concerned with the system install ruby version residing in `/usr/bin` as I understand that is tied to the OS and should simply be ignored.

How can I safely uninstall/remove the aforementioned version and all the places in which it was installed, short of looking at the `install` script?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a lot into the `README` file included with the source download.

```
  7. Run 'make install'

     This command will create following directories and install files
     onto them.

       * ${DESTDIR}${prefix}/bin
       * ${DESTDIR}${prefix}/include/ruby-${MAJOR}.${MINOR}.${TEENY}
       * ${DESTDIR}${prefix}/include/ruby-${MAJOR}.${MINOR}.${TEENY}/${PLATFORM}
       * ${DESTDIR}${prefix}/lib
       * ${DESTDIR}${prefix}/lib/ruby
       * ${DESTDIR}${prefix}/lib/ruby/${MAJOR}.${MINOR}.${TEENY}
       * ${DESTDIR}${prefix}/lib/ruby/${MAJOR}.${MINOR}.${TEENY}/${PLATFORM}
       * ${DESTDIR}${prefix}/lib/ruby/site_ruby
       * ${DESTDIR}${prefix}/lib/ruby/site_ruby/${MAJOR}.${MINOR}.${TEENY}
       * ${DESTDIR}${prefix}/lib/ruby/site_ruby/${MAJOR}.${MINOR}.${TEENY}/${PLATFORM}
       * ${DESTDIR}${prefix}/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
       * ${DESTDIR}${prefix}/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/${MAJOR}.${MINOR}.${TEENY}
       * ${DESTDIR}${prefix}/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/${MAJOR}.${MINOR}.${TEENY}/${PLATFORM}
       * ${DESTDIR}${prefix}/lib/ruby/gems/${MAJOR}.${MINOR}.${TEENY}
       * ${DESTDIR}${prefix}/share/man/man1
       * ${DESTDIR}${prefix}/share/ri/${MAJOR}.${MINOR}.${TEENY}/system
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't give a full file listing, and the folders mentioned are also used by other programs.

---

For a complete list of what `make install` installs, view the hidden file `.installed.list`. Just go into the source directory, and enter `less .installed.list` to view it on the command line, or `open .installed.list` to open it in a text editor.

Comment: In doing this, the amount of dirs touched, such as in usr/local/share, etc...seems wild. 16k+ lines listed in `.installed.list`. I am a bit nervous so go purge all those fiels/dirs.

Comment: @AaronMcIver It's actually not that many files other than the ones clearly Ruby (+version) related. I wouldn't remove the folders that aren't obviously Ruby, as they probably get `mkdir`ed just in case they don't exist.